# Twitter won't let me add 127.0.0.1 as the callback URL?

Tags: twitter, oauth

[image]

I'm trying to implement OAuth authentication with twitter. To test locally I need to add the callback URL (http://127.0.0.1/...) , However it says ***'Invalid website url'*** when I put in the localhost URL.

The documentation [callback-urls](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/apps/guides/callback-urls) states that this should be valid.

*(P.S. I did the same thing with Google where the localhost URL (http://127.0.0.1/...) was accepted)*

Comment: set it to http://localhost/auth/twitter/callback

Comment: Did you tried `http://localhost/auth/twitter/callback` ?

Comment: Yes, still says invalid url.

Comment: The documentation says to use  http(s)://127.0.0.1..   I would double check you dont have a space on the end or in the front.

Comment: I just double-checked and the spacing is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new developer account, This new account let me set any kind of callback URL I wanted including :

- http://localhost/auth/twitter/callback
- http://127.0.0.1/auth/twitter/callback

When creating your developer account make sure you don't say it's for academic or research purposes and specify that it's for a software/app you're going to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ngrok with the https url:
install it and then run it with the command : ngrok http "port_that_u_re_using"

Comment: The documentation says that  http(s)://127.0.0.1. is valid you dont have to use ngrok.

Comment: Yes the doc does say that, that's why I'm not opting to use ngrok.